# Be notified when the poolsize is reached

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In order to improve the pool design of an application, I would like to be notified (ideally with an event) when the pool size of an application is reached. This way, I can add a log, if this log occurs too often I will increase the pool size.

With a mongo client initialized this way :

```
const client = new MongoClient(url, {
  poolSize: 10,
});
```

Is there a way to be notified when the 10 connections are reached within my application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use connection pool events. These should be implemented by all recent MongoDB drivers.

[Node documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/monitoring)

[Documentation/example in Ruby](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#connection-pool-and-connection-monitoring)

For your question you would track the pool size using ConnectionCheckOut*/ConnectionCheckedIn events if your driver does not expose the pool size or the pool at all directly.

Comment: I guess I have no choice :/ I was hoping a way to avoid it. Thx